# Select all checkboxes with a text link

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have made a form with a "Select All" checkbox that selects all the other checkboxes within that that form.

I want to modify it so the select all function will work off of a text link, like below:

**Link**

```
<a href="#' id="checkall">Select all checkboxes</a>
```

Currently it works as below using another checkbox to select all the other checkboxes

**Form**

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">

<fieldset>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkall" id="checkall"> <label for="checkall">Check all</label></div>

<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"> <label for="checkbox1">Checkbox</label></div>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2"> <label for="checkbox2">Checkbox</label></div>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3"> <label for="checkbox3">Checkbox</label></div>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4"> <label for="checkbox4">Checkbox</label></div>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5"> <label for="checkbox5">Checkbox</label></div>

<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6"> <label for="checkbox6">Checkbox</label></div>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7" id="checkbox7"> <label for="checkbox7">Checkbox</label></div>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" id="checkbox8"> <label for="checkbox8">Checkbox</label></div>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox9" id="checkbox9"> <label for="checkbox9">Checkbox</label></div>
<div class="radio"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox10" id="checkbox10"> <label for="checkbox10">Checkbox</label></div>

</fieldset>

</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#checkall').click(function () {
    $('fieldset').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
});
</script>
```

I've looked online and can't find a solution for this, any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the checkbox to a link and replace `this.checked`, with `true` if all you want is for the link to always select all checkboxes.

**Update**
Try adding `data-checked="false"` as an attribute of the link in the HTML. Then the following should do the trick:

```
$('#checkall').click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).data('checked');
    $('fieldset').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', !checked);
    $(this).data('checked', !checked);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael Mior, that works brilliantly, just on thing, now it does not toggle between checked and unchecked, any idea how to keep that functionality? Thanks so much

Comment: Also, just a general note that in jQuery 1.6+, the correct way to set checked status is `.prop('checked', true)` instead of `.attr('checked', true)`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, works like a charm, it worked without adding the attribute to the link. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

you can do something  like this,

```
 $('#checkall').click(function () {
       var text=$(this).text(); 

       if (text=='Uncheck all'){
           $('fieldset').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
           $(this).text('Check all');
        }else{
          $('fieldset').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
          $(this).text('Uncheck all');
     }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jayantha, this is awesome, I gave the answer to the first one because he answered my original question first(just trying to be fair) but yours was actually more what I wanted. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

use `.prop` (available in jquery v-1.6 and +) also you have multiple elements by same id, that is not allowed/should be done

```
$("#checkallll").click(function(){

       if ($("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked"))
       {
           $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
           $(this).text('Check all');
        }
     else{
         $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
          $(this).text('Uncheck all');
     }        
 });
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AKJwF/

Comment: Thanks 3nigma, I haven't used prop before, I checked out the fiddle and it worked great but it wasn't working when I added it to my code, prob a conflict with something else I'm running, so I'm going to stick with Jayantha solution. Cheers

Comment: Hi, i just saw prop was only added from 1.6, I'm running 1.5, that's prob why it didn't work on my site. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we ended up doing because we wanted a toggle link - no messing with data attributes at all.

```
click: function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $checked = $('input[name=select_attachment]:checked:visible');
    var $unchecked = $('input[name=select_attachment]:unchecked:visible');    
    $checked.prop('checked', false);
    $unchecked.prop('checked', true);
    return false;
}
```