# Select all checkboxes with a text link: Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make a "select all" checkbox for a form based on the following link, but I keep getting errors. I've searched, but haven't had luck figuring this out. I'm not sure if I have the selectors set correctly. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

[Select all checkboxes with a text link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278943/select-all-checkboxes-with-a-text-link/7278993#7278993)

Form

```
<li id='field_1_17' class='gfield gfield_html gfield_html_formatted gfield_no_follows_desc' >
    <a href="#' id="checkall">Select all checkboxes</a>
</li>

<li id='field_1_12' class='gfield' >
    <label class='gfield_label'>Wednesday 1/22</label>
    <div class='ginput_container'>
        <ul class='gfield_checkbox' id='input_1_12'>
            <li class='gchoice_12_1'>
                <input name='input_12.1' type='checkbox' value='2:30-2:40 Welcome and introduction' id='choice_12_1' tabindex='11' />
                <label for='choice_12_1'>2:30-2:40 Welcome and introduction</label></li>
```

Script Used from other post

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#checkall').click(function () {
            var checked = $(this).data('checked');
            $('input_1_12').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', !checked);
            $(this).data('checked', !checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: No errors with this code, just nothing gets checked

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing dot.

```
$('input_1_12').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !checked);
```

Should be :

```
$('.input_1_12').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !checked);
```

Or even better:

```
$('.input_1_12[input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', !checked);
```

**Updated:**
Changed `attr()` to `prop()` because the attr method expects a string.

**Update 2:** here is what you can do with attr

```
var checked = $(this).data('checked'),
    checkboxes = $('.input_1_12[input[type="checkbox"]');
if (checked) {
    checkboxes.removeAttr("checked");
}else {
    checkboxes.attr("checked","checked");
}
```

Comment: second suggestion `.prop()`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried adding that in, but still nothing gets "checked" I do see the url being appended with "/#' id=" No errors show in the console

Answer (score 0):

An ID selector starts with `#`, and you should be using `prop()` to set the checked **property**!

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkall').on('click', function () {
        var checked = $(this).data('checked');
        $('#input_1_12 [type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', !checked);
        $(this).data('checked', !checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Adeno! unfortunately I tried this also, but no luck - as I mentioned above - "nothing gets 'checked' I do see the url being appended with "/#' id=" No errors show in the console"